# What does $e^{a*ln(x)}$ equal in terms of $a$ and $x$, and how is this found?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I saw somewhere that it would be $x^a$, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: $e^{a\cdot\ln{x}} = (e^{\ln{x}} )^a = x^a$ by definition of natural logs. We know $x>0$ since $\ln{x}$ is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two logarithm rules are needed:
$$\ln(a^b) = b\cdot \ln(a)$$
$$e^{\ln(x)} = x$$
And thus
$$e^{a\cdot \ln(x)} = e^{\ln(x^a)} = x^a$$

Answer (score 0):

$ln(x)$ is the power you need to raise $e$ to, to get $x$
Therefore, $e^{ln(x)}$ = $e$ raised to the power you need to raise e to, to get x. Thus,
$e^{ln(x)} = x$

And for $e^{a*ln(x)}$ use the log property:
$\ln(a^b) = b\cdot \ln(a)$

Answer (score -1):

$ e^{a*\ln(x)} = e^{\ln(x^a)} = x^a $